# Python string index out of range error?

Tags: python, string, indexing, range

I'm attempting to convert names from a first name first style to a family name first. The trick is getting it to accept input with or without a middle name.
My code as it stands:

```
import re 

def convertName(oldName):
    newName = oldName
    while newName == oldName:
        newName = re.sub('^  +', '',oldName)
        newName = re.sub('   +', ' ',newName)                         
        return newName

def main(firstName, middleName, lastName):
    finalName = (lastName + firstName + middleName)
    return finalName
name = 0
while name != "":
    name = str(input("Name ---- "))
    if name == "":
            print("Finished")
            break    
    newName = convertName(name)
    firstNameSplit = newName.find(" ")
    firstName = newName[:firstNameSplit]
    lastNameSplit = newName.rfind(" ") + 1
    lastName = newName[lastNameSplit:] + ', '
    middleNameSplit = newName[firstNameSplit:lastNameSplit]
    middleName =  middleNameSplit.strip()
    finalMiddleName = " " + middleName[0] + '.'
    finalName = main(firstName, finalMiddleName, lastName)
    print("Result --",finalName)
    print()
```

My current results:

```
Name ---- joshua example example
Result -- example, joshua e.

Name ---- joshua example
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 37, in 0
builtins.IndexError: string index out of range
```

Any tips/hints would be much appreciated!!

Eventually found out a working solution in the following:

```
newName = convertName(name)
    firstNameSplit = newName.find(" ")
    firstName = newName[:firstNameSplit]
    lastNameSplit = newName.rfind(" ") + 1
    lastName = newName[lastNameSplit:] + ', '
    middleNameSplit = newName[firstNameSplit:lastNameSplit]
    middleName =  middleNameSplit.strip()
    if middleName != "":
        finalMiddleName = " " + middleName[0] + '.'
    else:
        finalMiddleName = ""
    finalName = main(firstName, finalMiddleName, lastName)
    print("Result --",finalName)
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just do the following:

```
name = str(input("Name ---- "))
if len(name.split()) == 2:
    print("Result -- " + name[name.rfind(" "):] + ", " + name[:name.find(" ")] + " " + name[name.find(" ")+1] + ".")
if len(name.split()) == 1:
    print ("Result -- " + name[name.find(" "):] + ", " + name[:name.find(" ")])
else:
    print ("Sorry! Invalid name")
```

This implementation has only been tested in Python 2.7.5.

It uses the string methods .find() and .rfind() to find the indices of the start of the first name, middle name, and last name

len(name.split()) tests how many words are in the name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The only issue though is it must print the name even without the middle name. the result should be:
example, joshua

Comment: @Josh It does print out the name even without the middle name. `if name.count(" ") == 1:` checks if there is only one space in the name (i.e. it has only a first and last name) and formats it accordingly.

Comment: I see, however, my user is able to enter as many spaces as they want before, between, or after names and it has to format it accordingly. So unfortunately, counting the spaces after names won't yield the answer I'm looking for.
For Instance:
Name ----             joshua        example        example
Result -- example, joshua e.
or
Name ----          joshua            example
Result -- example, joshua
Thanks!

Comment: @Josh I have revised my answer to ignore extra whitespace. Now, it checks for the amount of words the name has.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance VedaadShakib. This morning I actually found a different solution which also found the intended result. I've edited a space in my solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem:

```
string = ""
print(string[0])
```

returns an error.

so, I fixed your main function, but you'll have to re-write the parser:

```
def main(firstName, lastName, middleName=""):
    if(middleName == ""):
        finalName = (lastName + " " + firstName)
    else:
        finalName = lastName + " " + firstName + " " + middleName[0] + "."

    return finalName
```